# Include link in html output

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using the following code to print error messages

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger login-fail">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ error }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

where error is provided into the template from my flask code as

```
...
return render_template('register.html', error="This is a test error message.")
```

I would like to include a hyperlink in this error message. If I do

```
    return render_template('register.html', error="This is a test error message <a href="http//example.com" </a>.")
```

it just prints this as a string. How can I make sure that html recognizes this as html code?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally flask escapes html tags. If you want to disable it replace {{ error }} with {{ error | safe}}. This prevents autoescaping.

Comment: hi jendas... thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know how to correctly include the link? If I do <a href="{{ url_for('reset-password') }}">text</a> the site tries to go to %7B%7B%20url_for('reset-password')%20%7D%7D

Comment: nevermind... I guess jinja2 in such a string is not working... I got it working with just <a href="/reset-password">text</a>

Comment: You can use flask.url_for in your code to get the url. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for